# Error when installing webpack module

Tags: windows, webpack, windows64

Error description:

> "/ Installing for-in@^0.1.5platform unsupported webpack@1.13.3 › watchpack@0.2.9 › chokidar@1.6.1 › fsevents@1.0.15 Package require os(darwin) not compatible with your platform(win32)
>   [fsevents@^1.0.0] optional install error: Package require os(darwin) not compatible with your platform(win32)"

I am sure that my platform is Windows 64. Please tell me why this error is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ignored error. fsevents is an optional dependency, is only used on macOS and not on Windows or Linux. You can simply ignore it! It always happens when using webpack (and many other packages) on Windows, it's perfectly normal and expected.